# Non-linear transformation of univariate normal variables: $y_i=\frac{e^{x_i}}{\sum_{j=1}^{K}{e^{x_j}}}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

Let $\{x_i\in\mathbb{R}\}_{i=1}^{K}$ be a set of random univariate variables, each of which is distributed normally as $x_i\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_{x,i},\sigma_{x,i}^2)$. Note that $x_i$'s are pairwise independent.

Also, let $\{y_i\in\mathbb{R}\}_{i=1}^{K}$ be the set of random variables, where each variable $y_i$ is given as the following non-linear transformation of $x_i$:
$$
y_i=\frac{e^{x_i}}{\sum_{j=1}^{K}{e^{x_j}}}.
$$
How could we find $y_i$'s mean $\mu_{y,i}$ and variance $\sigma_{y,i}^2$?

Comment: Nonnegative random variables distributed normally? This would be a surprise...

Comment: @Did correct, it's obviously not normal (I edit my question). But how could we compute $y_i$'s mean and variance?

Comment: Without assuming joint normality, and for unspecified parameters $\mu_i$ and $\sigma^2_i$, I doubt there is a theoretical answer. For given values of the parameters, simulations might be an option.

Comment: How would you compute expectation? Take the function, multiply by density and integrate: $\mathsf E[y_i] = \idotsint_{\mathbb{R}^K} e^{z_i} (\sum_{j=1}^K e^{z_j})^{-1} f(z_1,\dots,z_K) dz_1\dots dz_K$, where $f(z_1,\dots,z_K) = f_1(z_1)\dots f_K(z_K)$ is the joint density of $(x_1,\dots,x_K)$. As @Did wrote, there is no chance to get a closed form expression without some strong assumptions about the parameters.

Comment: @Did, zhoraster, thank you for your answers. Would it help if I assumed that $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,\ldots,x_K)\in\mathbf{R}^K$ is a mumtivariate normal vector with mean $\mu=(\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_K)$ and a covariance matrix $\Sigma$?

Comment: This would be even worse... When told that the setting is too wide, you still enlarge it?

Comment: @Did, apologies for my ignorance; this what I understood by "joint normality".

Comment: OK, you did restrict the setting by assuming joint normality but you widened it by stopping to (implictely) assume independence. Anyway, even with joint normality and independence, "for unspecified parameters μi and σ2i, I doubt there is a theoretical answer. For given values of the parameters, simulations might be an option."

Comment: @Did, thank you for your answer and explanation.

Comment: Specifications of this problem seem to be in flux. If this question is motivated by a practical application, you might want to look at Wikipedia on 'lognormal distributions' to see if anything there seems useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Unscented Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unscented_transform) to find mean and covariance. Let $y = f(x)$ be a linear or nonlinear mapping from $x$ to $y$. Given that you know the mean and covariance of $x$, you can find mean and covariance of $y$ by generating sigma points corresponding to $x$.